# How do I crop to least rectangular extent after Photomerge?

Tags: photoshop, panorama, cropping

After stitching a panorama using Photomerge, how can I crop out all the empty space on the sides? Seems like there should be a tool for this, but I can't find one in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing "R" (or "C" in older versions) should bring up the crop tool.

It is then self-explanatory. Just use the mouse to select the area you like to crop to. You can use the handles on the sides and corners for that, too.

## Option 2:

As explained [here](http://www.rickbakerimages.com/photography_advice/photomerge_panoramics3.html), you can go to `File > Automate > Crop and Straighten Photo...` and have it done for you.

Comment: You should probably write a bit more about how to use the tool too, not just where to find it. As this answer stands now, it's not very informative.

Comment: Tried the tool, that absolutely *does not* do what I describe above. It does straighten, yes, but I still end up with transparent edge content. Not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of Photoshop you're using but in Elements 11, I get a popup after it's finished photomerging asking me if I want Photoshop to automatically fill in the empty space around the edges.

I've never managed it though. I have 8Gb RAM but that's not enough as it chugs away for a while before running out of memory!! :(

Comment: What I think it does is a content aware fill of the empty space around the edges. This costs a lot of memory and for a panorama  (= big image) 8GB might not be enough. By manually selecting parts of the empty space and content aware filling it manually you can get around the memory limit.

Comment: We don't get a popup in Photoshop. Thus the question.